# Fork Programming in C at Linux Environment

Tags: c

Can anyone help me to know the fork process in c Programming and how it's working on the real time application.And sample program for that.

Comment: What have you figured out so far?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't quite tell what you're meaning to ask. Are you asking for an example of how to use `fork()` in C? If you are, there's an example on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(operating_system)) for `fork()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fork() execution process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010359/fork-execution-process)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        printf("child process\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("parent process\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "fork() returns twice, once in parent and once in child" should clear further questions...

Answer (score 1):

The complete reference of the C libraries is already on your PC, if it has Linux on it, at least. You can find almost every system call / supported C function via the man pages. Try typing `man fork` at the console and see what magic happens. :) You can search in the man pages by pressing the `/` key then type your string and press enter after that you can search for the next occurrence by pressing `n`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec) states

```
Fork-exec is a commonly used technique in Unix whereby an executing process
spawns a new program
```

Related SO question : [Applications of fork system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345320/applications-of-fork-system-call)

Sample code: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html