# Apache2, PHP file always running and accessible from any request

Tags: php, multithreading, asynchronous, pthreads, apache2

Is there any way to make a php file always running and accessible from others php files/requests?

I want to make a functions, objects, variables or some others things always running on the server.

Example:

[alwaysrunning.php]

```
$conn = fsockopen($serverip, $serverport, $errno, $errstr, $ex);
```

[index.php]

```
fwrite($conn, $command."\n");
```

Sorry my english and thank you!

Comment: Include your functions in a file (somefunctions.php).  Then in your index.php file, include them: `require_once('...PATH.../somefunctions.php');`  Then call the functions required to initiate connections and others.  Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458837/how-to-define-global-functions-in-php

Comment: @Nic3500 i don't want include, i want that variable never die, always running, like in other thread.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? There's no technical reason this can't be done, but it's definitely not a common pattern.

Comment: I wonder how to use that file without including. A singleton pattern might help you

Comment: PHP is inherently stateless, the request starts, the caller receives a response and that's that. If you want to maintain state PHP is not the answer. If you want to have access to it in the current request(something like a global state), that's a different matter.

Comment: Read this one, very detailed!   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268018/concurrent-use-of-a-persistent-php-socket   and http://php.net/manual/en/function.pfsockopen.php.  Seems feasible after all!

Comment: @Andrew are you suggesting me to use another language? Which one would you recommend?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve here. I don't want to suggest languages just because. Maybe if you'd explain in greater detail what you're aiming for I'm sure people would come up with a more suitable result.

Comment: @Nic3500 i used 'fsockopen' as an example, but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @Andrew & iainn :: I'm not doing anything in particular, I'm just looking for ways to make code more efficiently due to the fact that connections are usually the bottleneck of my systems.

Comment: Well in that case a different language is not the answer. Even if you kept a persistent connection it's still a connection. And PHP does offer that too [pecl_http](https://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http). If you want to have access to the information in the file on a regular basis nginx is really good at serving static content or just use a CDN and solve the connection to your system all together.

Comment: *"I'm just looking for ways to make code more efficiently due to the fact that connections are usually the bottleneck of my systems"* you should have mentioned that in your question , you are a victim to [XY questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @Accountantم What I am looking for is to be able to execute tasks in a main thread and that different connections/requests can access and modify them, not only make connections.

Comment: @Andrew What I am looking for is to be able to execute tasks in a main thread and that different connections/requests can access and modify them, not only make connections.

Comment: @xXNurioXx AFAIK PHP is designed for request-response pattern. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469870/how-do-real-time-strategy-games-work-in-php#comment11982999_9469870), it might help

Comment: @Accountantم i'm not trying to code real time update site, i just want to increase the server performance, and minimize the response time.
My question is not how to solve any problem, I am asking if what I want currently has a form.

Comment: @xXNurioXx Please don't try to fix something that has nothing to do with performance and waste your resources. You **must profile** your software to know where exactly are the bottlenecks. May be it is just a SQL query that needs an optimization, or may be it's the server network infrastructure and your code doesn't need anything. However take a look at [PHP opcode cashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296978/what-is-the-easiest-way-for-opcode-caching-with-php-apache?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)