# How to write a script that runs as long as the server is up?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I am using a WAMP server.

Is it possible to run a script as long as WAMP server is on? If so, how? If it can't be done, can XAMPP do it or any other development server?

**Edit:**
I want to run a PHP script then insert data in the database on specific dates and I am using Windows 7.

Comment: It's possible. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to run a PHP script then insert data in the database on specific dates.

Comment: If you need something permanent, don't use a request based scripting language but e.g. setup a Tomcat and use Java/JSP (or some other technology).

Answer (score 3):

Based on comments:

You're looking at the problem wrong. Write a script and use a Cron job for it. If you're on a windows machine, scheduled tasks work too.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to run a PHP script then insert data in the database on specific dates.

Use a cronjob. Most control panels offer them, else use `crontab` on linux or the task scheduler in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write this kind of script:

```
<?php

while (true) {
    // Do something
}
```

And then launch it using the PHP CLI (command line) :

```
php your_script.php
```

Comment: That would lock the PHP process and prevent all further requests.

Comment: No it won't, it depends on what you put inside the `while` loop (think `sleep(1000);` for instance). A cron is not always enough, it depends on what JohnSmith wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are describing a daemon.  If your scrpit breaks you need the functionality so it can handle errors and resume itself.
[Run php script as daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process)

Creating a daemon in PHP seems like it is an en devour but provides the functionality you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Use Window's Task Scheduler / Manager (run taskschd.msc) to do this...

It's like cron but for Windows.

You can give it a URL to hit every so often (via executing cURL, wget, powershell, VBS, IE/Firefox/Chrome), or use it to directly execute a PHP script via php.exe.

For example, if I wanted to run a PHP file (via my Wamp-Developer), I would just add a task that executes this...

```
C:\WampDeveloper\Components\Php\php.exe -f "C:\my_php_file.php"
```

You can specifiy for it to also use / or not use the php.ini file (check php --help).

Or..

```
C:\WampDeveloper\Tools\curl\curl.exe http://localhost/my_php_file.php
```

You can HEAD, POST, login, etc with cURL...
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html

Since you're using WampServer, you'd just update the Wamp-Developer paths above and it should work (I don't know where WampServer or Xampp places php or curl).