# How to respawn PHP script using upstart?

Tags: php, upstart

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 installation and a PHP script I want to re-run as soon as it terminates.  I'm using upstart and this `myscript.conf` in `/etc/init/`:

```
start on startup
stop on shutdown
exec php5 /var/myscript.php
respawn
```

I can run my script using `start myscript`, which works fine one-time, but I can't get the script to respawn once it terminates.

Is there something special I have to pay attention to when trying to respawn a PHP script?

Comment: I just added sleep(5) to the beginning of my PHP script and it now respawns as expected. I'm not sure why this help, but it does.

Comment: Had the same experience, and `sleep(5)` is exactly how I fixed it as well. I actually answered another question with a [more thorough example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process/16577806#16577806) of my Upstart script.

Answer (score 2):

You can update your script very easy when you have a startscript under `/etc/init.d`

`update-rc.d myscript defaults`

But then you need a startscript. You can checkout the skeleton script (/etc/init.d/skeleton) and copy the script. Then you can change the params and run your programm.

like this: `/etc/init.d/myscript start`

In the startscript you can kill the process if its not terminating correct.