# Make php script run as service linux

Tags: php, linux, service, daemon, startup

I have a php script written, and I want  run it as a `service/daemon` in linux.

So i can use service myservice `start/stop/restart`

I am assuming it needs to be in the `/etc/init.d/`

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference of any prebuilt startup script under `/etc/init.d` for eg httpd.
For eg you can take a reference of below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# chkconfig: 35 90 12
# description: Foo server
#
# Get function from functions library
. /etc/init.d/functions
# Start the service FOO
start() {
       initlog -c "echo -n Starting FOO server: "
    /path/to/FOO &
    ### Create the lock file ###
    touch /var/lock/subsys/FOO
    success $"FOO server startup"
    echo
}
# Restart the service FOO
stop() {
    initlog -c "echo -n Stopping FOO server: "
    killproc FOO
    ### Now, delete the lock file ###
    rm -f /var/lock/subsys/FOO
    echo
}
### main logic ###
case "$1" in
start)
    start
    ;;
stop)
    stop
    ;;
 status)
    status FOO
        ;;
 restart|reload|condrestart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
 *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
    exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

You can have detailed look [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html)

Comment: In the path to section, won't I have to add something because it is a php file?

Comment: You can tweak a little this `bash` script,  `/path/to/FOO &` you can run your script and check for its $?, if it is healthy enough it should be started or failed if not healthy.

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process)