# How to make script that runs all the time?

Tags: javascript, php, web

I would like to make a script that would run all the time at server or at least at certain times, because I have some actions I want to do at certain times.
For now I have a script that refreshes every 1 second and that is good, but only in case when user is on the site. When site is not opened, it doesn't work.
Any solutions?

**EDIT:**
What would be better choice of suggested solutions, cron job or PHP daemon?

Comment: use a cron job.

Comment: It would be perfect if it could run every second

Comment: Within a while loop, at the bottom of the script, you could add sleep(1); which would stop the script for 1 second.

Comment: But I need cron job that way, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a Linux system, then you could use the CRON Daemon which allows users to execute scripts or commands (or groups of commands) at a specified time.

You would schedule a CRON event using Crontab (CRON Table). Crontab is a file which contains the list of all cron jobs and at what time they're due to run (think of it as a schedule)

Creating an entry into Crontab has it's own peculiar syntax beyond the scope of this post, but for [more information](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your PHP to run as a daemon.  I've implemented this for some of my scripts that need to check for data constantly.

I used `Upstart` for this job and pretty much followed the path from this post on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16577806/3293987

He also has links to the source where he learned it from.