# Run multiple workers with upstart daemon

Tags: php, shell, unix, daemon, upstart

I was wondering whether it is possible to have multiple php worker with upstart. My problem is that one worker isn't enough for my tasks anymore so I'd love to have 2-3 worker. Even better would be to automatically scale the number of workers.

I'm using:

```
# Info
description "My PHP Worker"
author      "Jonathan"

# Events
start on startup
stop on shutdown

# Automatically respawn
respawn
respawn limit 20 5

# Run the script!
# Note, in this example, if your PHP script returns
# the string "ERROR", the daemon will stop itself.
script
    [ $(exec /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/your/script.php) = 'ERROR' ] && ( stop; exit 1; )
end script
```

Found at [Run php script as daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process) thx @Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Basically, have one instance job with no start on and a stop on as `stop-myworkers`. Then have another job which starts a few workers with different instance ids at boot in a pre-start script and emits the aforementioned stop event on shutdown.