# Run php script as systemd service in centos7

Tags: php, centos7, systemd

I 'm trying to run a phpscript on startup of centos7. Currently systemd process looks like below

```
[Unit]
Description=custom Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/htdocs/mysite/public/index.php abc xyz >> /var/log/custom.log 2>&1 


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But above script is not passing arguments. How could I fix the issue ? Thanks!

Comment: pass those as normal params o_O

Comment: `var_dump($argv);` this will help us much better

Comment: What you mean by normal parameters ?

Comment: Executing /usr/bin/php /var/www/htdocs/mysite/public/index.php abc xyz from linux commandline works as expected. only the systemd script doesnt work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process/44420339#44420339

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, I've created a `myphp.sh` bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup /usr/bin/php /var/www/htdocs/mysite/public/index.php abc xyz & >> /var/log/custom.log 2>&1
```

and then in systemd script

```
[Unit]
Description=custom Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/myphp.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try with this configuration

```
[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
PHP_PARAM_1=abc
PHP_PARAM_2=xyz
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/htdocs/mysite/public/index.php $PHP_PARAM_1 $PHP_PARAM_2>> /var/log/custom.log 2>&1
```

**UPDATE**

```
[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
Environment="abc xyz"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/htdocs/mysite/public/index.php $PHP_PARAM_1 $PHP_PARAM_2>> /var/log/custom.log 2>&1
```

Comment: `ExecStart` does not support shell features like redirection. It's what would be passed to `execve()`, which is just a path to a program and a list of arguments, separated by spaces. That's why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is but a hunch, but I think the prefix in the `ExecStart` option (`/usr/bin/php ...`) is messing up the argument ordering and that's why you cant use those args properly. I suspect you can mitigate this issue by using a shebang in your php script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

// YOUR PHP CODE HERE
```

You also need to add exec rights to the files. This way, you can use the php script just like any other shell script, so you can just simply omit the prefix part from your `ExecStart` parameter:

```
ExecStart=/var/www/htdocs/mysite/public/index.php $PHP_PARAM_1 $PHP_PARAM_2 >> /var/log/custom.log 2>&1
```