# How do I start a php server in the background as a daemon in a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, upstart, ratchet, docker-container

I was trying to follow the tutorial here using upStart ([Run php script as daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process)), but I ran into some snags when I get the error `'startserver: unrecognized service'`

Here is some images to show what I tried

[image]

[image]

At the bottom of the console is where the errors are. I also show proof that my file is in /etc/init where it should be in the docker container.  I logged in using `docker exec -it draftandpermit_web_1 bash`

**Am I missing something?**

Other Reference Data:

**startserver.conf**

```
# Info
description "Start Server"
author      "Joseph Astrahan"

# Events
start on startup
stop on shutdown

# Automatically respawn
respawn
respawn limit 20 5

# Run the script!
# Note, in this example, if your PHP script returns
# the string "ERROR", the daemon will stop itself.
script
    [ $(exec /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/callcenter/livesite/bin/startwebsocketserver.php) = 'ERROR' ] && ( stop; exit 1; )
end script
```

I activate it either manually as you saw in the images or using my convenience script

```
echo "Copying startserver.conf to /etc/init"
docker exec -it draftandpermit_web_1 bash -c "cd /app/docker; cp -f startserver.conf /etc/init/"

echo "Stopping & Starting the WebSocket & HTTP Server"
docker exec -it draftandpermit_web_1 bash -c "service startserver stop"
docker exec -it draftandpermit_web_1 bash -c "service startserver start"
```

Keep in mind paths are correct for where the file is since I manually went into the container to look at /etc/init as shown in the images.

Comment: 'running as a deamon' and docker is a warning sign: docker needs to be running something, if you run it in the background, your docker will say: well, there's no process, so I can quit. Why do you want to run it as daemon?

Comment: I don't want to run docker as a daemon but a process in the background in docker

Comment: Basically trying to use upstart in a docker container to start my php service

Comment: I meant: you shouldn't be running background processes in docker. Docker stops if your command exits. you should probably not run it troufh upstart, just do your php command as the docker command?

Comment: I can't do this because if I close the terminal window the process stops for the php server

Comment: I'm basically running a rachet php web socket server

Comment: I can't really make it any clearer. If you have a docker container, you want it to run one single process. An actual process, not a daemon. That's how its supposed to work, so you should try and figure out  how to run your process  without the server.  I think you should start looking for a different way to run whatever you want to run, maybe ask that as a question? I'm not too confident this can work out. Anyway, good luck :)

Comment: I think i get what you are saying now I just didn't realize docker run has an option to ignore output with -d essentially being a background task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is neither an init system nor does it run traditional init systems without some hacks. The first process you run in the Docker container will be PID 1. This could be a supervisor (like supervisord, s6, dumb-init).

However, more generally, you can just run the process you want and handle running in the foreground or background with options to the `docker run` command. In this example your Docker command (or `CMD` in the `Dockerfile`) can just be `php -f /var/www/callcenter/livesite/bin/startwebsocketserver.php`. Then, run your container with the `-d` option and it will run in the background. You can attach to it with `docker attach` or just watch the output with `docker logs`.

If you actually need to use some sort of process supervisor (such as, when you need to have multiple processes running in the container), then I'd start looking to Docker init options out there. I mentioned a couple and there are more. Upstart won't work inside a container.

Comment: Currently I am using docker compose with the -d option to start the containers.  I then volume in my Code the same way. Are you saying the run command also has a -d option?

Comment: If so that would work for sure.  I didn't even think of that will have to try it

Comment: If I run with -d how do I stop the server to restart it?

Comment: Look up `docker stop`, `docker kill`, and `docker rm -f`

Comment: Thanks for responding, however, that will kill the entire docker container, what if I only want to kill just the php server running process that is running in the container?

Comment: If you are running a supervisor as PID 1 in the container then you would have to control the other processes via that supervisor control. If you need to exec a command to do that you can do something like `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` to get a shell and then execute your supervisor control command.