# telegram bot buttons change into one

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

what I am trying to achieve is that when someone clicks button for example 'done' there should be one button with 'done' text in it and if user clicks that single button - all three previous buttons should be shown again.
The text above the buttons should remain the same all the time.
All of it should be in php.
My code is:

```
    $data = [
            'text' => 'some text here' 
];
$keyboard = json_encode([

        "inline_keyboard" => [

            [
                [
                    "text" => "Done",
                    "callback_data" => "done"
                ],
                [
                    "text" => "Cancel",
                    "callback_data" => "cancel"
                ],
                [
                    "text" => "processing",
                    "callback_data" => "processing"
                ],

            ]
        ]
    ],true);            
      
 $url ="https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?".http_build_query($data). "&parse_mode=html".'&reply_markup='.$keyboard;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Telegram Inline keyboards PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60529715/telegram-inline-keyboards-php)

Comment: @0stone0, hi , no, it doesn't