# Why fork() before setsid()

Tags: c, linux, system, unix

Why `fork()` before `setsid()` to daemonize a process?

Basically, if I want to detach a process from its controlling terminal and make it a process group leader : I use `setsid()`.

Doing this without forking before doesn't work.

Why?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First of all: setsid() will make your process a process group leader, but it will also make you the leader of a new session. If you are just interested in getting your own process group, then use setpgid(0,0).

Now for understanding the actual reason why setsid() returns EPERM if you already are process group leader or session leader you have to understand that process group and session ids are initialized from the process id of the process creating them (and hence leading them, i.e. for a session leader pid == sid and for a process group leader pid == pgid). Also process groups cannot move between sessions.

That means if you are a process group leader, and creating a new session would be allowed then the sid and the pgid would get set to your pid, leaving the other processes in your old process group in a weird state: their process group leader suddenly is in a different session then they themselves might be. And that cannot be allowed, hence the EPERM by the kernel.

Now if you fork() once you are neither session nor process group leader anymore and hence setting your sid and pgid to your pid is safe, because there are no other processes in such group.

So, yepp, think about it, it all makes sense.

Comment: Could you please give some reference documentation that explains what means that process is a process group leader, and why this matters.

Comment: If a process group leader is allowed to call `setsid()`, create a new session and a new process group, it may lead to a process group id conflict.

Answer (score 20):

It is required to `fork()` and have the child call `setsid()` to ensure that the process calling `setsid()` isn't already a process group leader (`setsid()` wants to make the calling process the process group leader of a *new* process group, so it fails in that case).

Answer (score 2):

`man 2 setsid`, you will get the following description:

> setsid() creates a new session if the calling process is not a process group leader. The calling process is the leader of the new session, the process group leader of the new process group, and has no controlling terminal. The process group ID and session ID of the calling process are set to the PID of the calling process. The calling process will be the only process in this new process group and in this new session.

If a process group leader is allowed to call `setsid()`, create a new session and a new process group(with the same process group id), it will lead to a process group id conflict.