# git post-receive hook not running in background

Tags: python, linux, git, background-process

According to the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) the post-receive hook essentially blocks the repo until it is completed:

> ... the client doesn’t disconnect until it has completed, so be careful if you try to do anything that may take a long time.

This causes a problem if you need the hook to kick off a build job and then poll for it's completion before kicking off another, say deploy, job.  For example, the build server cannot fetch from the repo while said script is running.

Let's also assume that you have absolutely no ability to place your script on the git server to be executed as a shell command with the whole `nohup /usr/bin/env python /path/to/post_receive.py 2>&1 > /dev/null &` approach similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917324/git-post-commit-hook-as-a-background-task).

Let's also assume that you have tried the whole double `os.fork()`'ing daemon process similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355995/fork-and-exit-in-python) and a few other questions (**non-working** sample code below) and found that git still waits for the long-running child to finish before completing the hook.

```
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    os.setsid()
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        long_running_post_receive_function()
    else:
        os._exit(0)
else:
    for fd in range(0, 3):
        os.close(fd)
    os._exit(0)
```

So, with these constraints, has anyone been successful with a long running python post-receive hook that actually runs in the background without blocking the repo?

**EDIT**

**working** minimal structure with no exception handling... thanks to @torek and @jthill

```
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    os.setsid()
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        for fd in range(0, 3):
            os.close(fd)
        long_running_post_receive_function()
    else:
        os._exit(0)
else:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: You could also employ some sort of producer/consumer model where the post-receive hook sends some sort of 'asynchronous message' (which could be as simple as touching a file) which causes a consumer daemon to notice this and do its work.

Comment: I certainly agree that this is an alternative it really defeats the purpose of what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: I'm tired, but it looks to me like you're doing your dup2()'s in the wrong place. The fd's are still open in the long-running process.

Comment: @jthill that was it!  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close down all descriptor access, so that ssh knows it will never get any more data.  In other words, call `os.close` on descriptors 0 through 2.  In practice you need those to be *open* though, so it's better to open `os.devnull` and `os.dup2` the resulting descriptor over 0, 1, and 2 (for truly robust software make sure `os.open` doesn't already return a value `0 <= fd <= 2`, of course—if it does, that's OK, just keep it in place while dup2-ing the rest).

(You still also need the usual double-fork trick, and it may be wise to ditch session IDs and so on.  In some Unix-derived systems there is a library routine called `daemon`, which may be in libc or libutil, that does all this for you.  Some details are inevitably OS-dependent, such as the way to give up the controlling terminal if any.  However, the main thing missing from your linked Python-specific answer is the replacement of the stdin/stdout/stderr descriptors.)

Comment: unless I have made a mistake or left something out this still doesn't seem to work.  I have edited my question with a sample of what I tried.

Comment: What does any of this mean!?!?

Comment: @JoeZim: there's a fair bit of deep(ish) Unix/Linux specific stuff here; which parts are you concerned with?

Comment: @torek at first I was confused because it wasn't working. I read closer and now I'm aware it's Python not Bash script. In any case, I don't understand what we're `close`ing, but truly understanding this doesn't matter too much. Right now, I'm just curious if there's a way to do this with Bash instead of Python?

Comment: You can do the close operations from a shell, using redirection. The reason we need to rewire stdout and/or stderr (whichever ones are connected to ssh—normally both) is that the ssh running on the client host is waiting for the "no more data will ever arrive" indicator to go through the communications link (the socket). To make that happen, from a Unix-ish machine, there must be *no* open file descriptors that could feed input across that socket. So if we do `longrunningcmd </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &`, we make sure that `longrunningcmd` doesn't hold the fd's open.