# Why fork() twice

Tags: c, debugging, fork

Nagios lets me configure `child_processes_fork_twice=<0/1>`.

The [documentation](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/configmain.html#child_processes_fork_twice) says

> This option determines whether or not Nagios will fork() child processes twice when it executes host and service checks. By default, Nagios fork()s twice. However, if the use_large_installation_tweaks option is enabled, it will only fork() once.

As far as I know `fork()` will spawn a new child process. *Why would I want to do that twice?*

Comment: @larsmans Thank you for that link. It wasn't on my list when I was researching the question first. I just learned a lot there and placed some upvotes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Linux, a daemon is typically created by forking twice with the intermediate process exiting after forking the grandchild. This has the effect of orphaning the grandchild process. As a result, it becomes the responsibility of the OS to clean up after it if it terminates. The reason has to do with what are known as zombie processes which continue to live and consume resources after exiting because their parent, who'd normally be responsible for the cleaning up, has also died.

Comment: I fail to see how this is better than forking just once. I think the real reason has something to do with sessions and controlling terminals, not orphaning, but I may be mistaken...

Comment: The main reason is if you start your daemon in a login session, double fork would make the daemon process having init (pid 1) being its parent, and when you log out of the session, the SIGHUP will not kill the process. It should not have anything to do with zombie process, as normally the main cause of zombie process is the parent process is not "wait()" on the terminated child process, and the os is keeping the return value of the child process, waiting for its parent to get. So in zombie process, the process is already exited, but kept by the OS, so not really dead, thus the name zombie.

Answer (score 81):

All right, so now first of all: what is a zombie process?
 It's a process that is dead, but its parent was busy doing some other work, hence it could not collect the child's exit status. 
 In some cases, the child runs for a very long time, the parent cannot wait for that long, and will continue with it's work (note that the parent doesn't die, but continues its remaining tasks but doesn't care about the child). 
 In this way, a zombie process is created.
 Now let's get down to business. How does forking twice help here? 
 The important thing to note is that the grandchild does the work which the parent process wants its child to do.
 Now the first time fork is called, the first child simply forks again and exits. This way, the parent doesn't have to wait for a long time to collect the child's exit status (since the child's only job is to create another child and exit). So, the first child doesn't become a zombie.
 As for the grandchild, its parent has already died. Hence the grandchild will be adopted by the `init` process, which always collects the exit status of all its child processes. So, now the parent doesn't have to wait for very long, and no zombie process will be created.
 There are other ways to avoid a zombie process; this is just a common technique.
 Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah.  Relationships are complicated.  And init is a kind old soul to adopt the grandchildren.

Answer (score 5):

Also from the [documentation](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/largeinstalltweaks.html),

> Normally Nagios will fork() twice when it executes host and service checks. This is done to (1) ensure a high level of resistance against plugins that go awry and segfault and (2) make the OS deal with cleaning up the grandchild process once it exits.

Answer (score 4):

[Unix Programming Faq](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/programmer/faq/) §1.6.2:

> ### 1.6.2 How do I prevent them from occuring?
>
> You need to ensure that your parent process calls `wait()` (or
>   `waitpid()`, `wait3()`, etc.) for every child process that terminates;
>   or, on some systems, you can instruct the system that you are
>   uninterested in child exit states.
>
> Another approach is to `fork()` *twice*, and have the immediate child
>   process exit straight away. This causes the grandchild process to be
>   orphaned, so the init process is responsible for cleaning it up. For
>   code to do this, see the function `fork2()` in the examples section.
>
> To ignore child exit states, you need to do the following (check your
>   system's manpages to see if this works):
>
> ```
>      struct sigaction sa;
>      sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
>  #ifdef SA_NOCLDWAIT
>      sa.sa_flags = SA_NOCLDWAIT;
>  #else
>      sa.sa_flags = 0;
>  #endif
>      sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
>      sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);
> ```
>
> If this is successful, then the `wait()` functions are prevented from
>   working; if any of them are called, they will wait until *all* child
>   processes have terminated, then return failure with `errno == ECHILD`.
>
> The other technique is to catch the SIGCHLD signal, and have the
>   signal handler call `waitpid()` or `wait3()`. See the examples section
>   for a complete program.

Comment: This only makes sense if the parent process is going to stick around after the child (or grandchild) is started. If the entire program is the daemon and the parent is going to exit immediately anyway, I see no benefit to the double fork, at least not with respect to orphaning the process.

Answer (score 2):

This code demonstrates how to use the double `fork` method to allow the grandchild process to become adopted by init, without risk of zombie processes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t p1 = fork();

    if (p1 != 0)
    {
        printf("p1 process id is %d", getpid());
        wait();
        system("ps");
    }
    else
    {
        pid_t p2 = fork();
        int pid = getpid();

        if (p2 != 0) 
        {
            printf("p2 process id is %d", pid);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("p3 process id is %d", pid);
        }

        exit(0);
    }
}
```

The parent will `fork` the new child process, and then `wait` for it to finish.  The child will `fork` a grandchild process, and then `exit(0)`.

In this case, the grandchild doesn't do anything except `exit(0)`, but could be made to do whatever you'd like the daemon process to do.  The grandchild may live long and will be reclaimed by the `init` process, when it is complete.

Comment: [An explanation would be nice.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Op is actually asking why the program is written like the way you have written

Comment: @MichaelGaskill thanks for the edit. I'll remove my comment.