# Can not understand the pipe() in my own shell

Tags: c, shell, unix, pipe

This is the code i found for my own shell.  It works fine,  but the thing i can't understand is pipe section of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* cmndtkn[256];
char buffer[256];
char* path=NULL;
char pwd[128];


int main(){

//setting path variable 
    char *env;
    env=getenv("PATH"); 
    putenv(env);
    system("clear");


printf("\t MY OWN SHELL !!!!!!!!!!\n ");
printf("_______________________________________\n\n");

while(1){

    fflush(stdin);
    getcwd(pwd,128);
    printf("[MOSH~%s]$",pwd);
    fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
    buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0';

    //tokenize the input command line   
    char* tkn = strtok(buffer," \t\n");
    int i=0;
    int indictr=0;



        // loop for every part of the command
        while(tkn!=NULL)
        {

            if(strcoll(tkn,"exit")==0 ){
                exit(0);                
            }

            else if(strcoll(buffer,"cd")==0){
            path = buffer;
            chdir(path+=3);
            }

            else if(strcoll(tkn,"|")==0){
            indictr=i;
            }

            cmndtkn[i++] = tkn;
            tkn = strtok(NULL," \t\n");
        }cmndtkn[i]='\0';

// execute when command has pipe. when | command is found indictr is greater than 0.
    if(indictr>0){

        char* leftcmnd[indictr+1];
        char* rightcmnd[i-indictr];
        int a,b;

        for(b=0;b<indictr;b++)
            leftcmnd[b]=cmndtkn[b];
        leftcmnd[indictr]=NULL;

        for(a=0;a<i-indictr-1;a++)
            rightcmnd[a]=cmndtkn[a+indictr+1];
        rightcmnd[i-indictr]=NULL;

        if(!fork())
        {   
            fflush(stdout);
            int pfds[2];
            pipe(pfds);

                if(!fork()){
                    close(1);
                    dup(pfds[1]);
                    close(pfds[0]);
                    execvp(leftcmnd[0],leftcmnd);
                }   
                else{
                    close(0);
                    dup(pfds[0]);
                    close(pfds[1]);
                    execvp(rightcmnd[0],rightcmnd);
                }
        }else
            wait(NULL);

//command not include pipe 

    }else{
        if(!fork()){
        fflush(stdout);
        execvp(cmndtkn[0],cmndtkn);

        }else
            wait(NULL);
    }

}

}
```

What is the purpose of the calls to close() with parameters of 0 and 1 mean and what does the call to dup() do?

Comment: Get some [easy tutorial from here](http://www.ccse.kfupm.edu.sa/~akbar/ICS431_031/LabExercises/Exercises.html)

Comment: @user315052 @xaxxon  I have a problem in understanding the `cd` section also.  I cannot understand why it assigns buffer to the path and the code segment of `chdir(path+=3)`.  Can someone please explain it..

Comment: @VirajLakshitha: You can't keep expanding the scope of your question like this. Ask a new question if you must, but next time put more effort in demonstrating that you have tried to answer the question yourself. Otherwise, it's not a real question, but a request for someone to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix, the `dup()` call uses the lowest numbered unused file descriptor. So, the `close(1)` before the call to `dup()` is to coerce `dup()` to use file descriptor 1. Similarly for `close(0)`.

So, the aliasing is to get the process to use the write end of the pipe for `stdout` (file descriptor 1 is used for console output), and the read end of the pipe for `stdin` (file descriptor 0 is used for console input).

The code may have been more clearly expressed with `dup2()` instead.

```
dup2(fd[1], 1); /* alias fd[1] to 1 */
```

---

From your question about how `ls | sort` works, your question is not limited to why the `dup()` system call is being made. Your question is actually how pipes in Unix work, and how a shell command pipeline works.

A pipe in Unix is a pair of file descriptors that are related in that writing data on tje writable descriptor allows that data to be read from the readable descriptor. The `pipe()` call returns this pair in an array, where the first array element is readable, and second array element is writable.

In Unix, a `fork()` followed by some kind of `exec()` is the only way to produce a new process (there are other library calls, such as `system()` or `popen()` that create processes, but they call `fork()` and do an `exec()` under the hood). A `fork()` produces a child process. The child process sees the return value of `0` from the call, while the parent sees a non-zero return value that is either the PID of the child process, or a `-1` indicating that an error has occurred.

The child process is a duplicate of the parent. This means that when a child modifies a variable, it is modifying a copy of the variable that resides in its own process. The parent does not see the modification occur, as the parent has the original copy). However, a duplicated pair of file descriptors that form a pipe can be used to allow a child process its parent to communicate with each other.

So, `ls | sort` means that there are two processes being spawned, and the output written by  `ls` is being read as input by `sort`. Two processes means two calls to `fork()` to create two child processes. One child process will `exec()` the `ls` command, the other child process will `exec()` the `sort` command. A pipe is used between them to allow the processes to talk to each other. The `ls` process writes to the writable end of the pipe, the `sort` process reads from the readable end of the pipe.

The `ls` process is coerced into writing into the writable end of the pipe with the `dup()` call after issuing `close(1)`. The `sort` process is coerced into reading the readable end of the pipe with the `dup()` call after `close(0)`.

In addition, the `close()` calls that close the pipe file descriptors are used to make sure that the `ls` process is the only process to have an open reference to the writable fd, the the `sort` process is the only process to have an open reference to the readable fd. That step is important because after `ls` exits, it will close the writable end of the fd, and the `sort` process will expect to see an EOF as a result. However, this will not occur if some other process still has the writable fd open.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain what happens if I enter the command 'ls | sort' .  I know that the output of 'ls' is going to be an input for 'sort'.  But how will it be executed?? I am asking this because 'ls' and 'sort' commands are stored in two different arrays. How can they be executed using 'execvp' when they are in if block and the relevant else block. @xaxxon

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29

stdin is file descriptor 0.

stdout is file descriptor 1.

In the !fork section, the process closes stdout then calls dup on pfds[1] which according to:

http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup

Creates a duplicate of the specified file descriptor at the lowest available position, which will be 1, since it was just closed (and stdin hasn't been closed yet).  This means everything sent to stdout will really go to pfds[1].

So, basically, it's setting up the two new processes to talk to each other.  the !fork section is for the new child which will send data to stdout (file descriptor 1), the parent (the else block) closes stdin, so it really reads from pfds[0] when it tries to read from stdout.

Each process has to close the file descriptor in pfds it's not using, as there are two open handles to the file now that the process has forked.  Each process now execs to left/right-cmnd, but the new stdin and stdout mappings remain for the new processes.

Forking twice is explained here: [Why fork() twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932592/why-fork-twice)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain what happens if I enter the command `ls | sort` . I know that the output of `ls` is going to be an input for `sort`. But how will it be executed?? I am asking this because `ls` and `sort` commands are stored in two different arrays. How can they be executed using `execvp` when they are in if block and the relevant else block.

Comment: 'ls' writes the results to stdout, right?  'sort' reads from stdin.  Now they are connected because 'ls' is actually writing to one end of the pipe that 'sort' is reading it's stdin from.

Comment: can u explain please why should I use two `fork()` system calls when executing a pipe??