# Exec() and Fork()

Tags: c, unix, posix, daemon

So i created a c program in unix. This is what it does.

1)It forks a process.

Child Process:
Performs execv() on a alarm clock program which prints "Alarm rang" after 'x' seconds

Parent Process:
Performs waitPID on child above.
Then exits.

Output:
So i ran it and i received the "Alarm rang after x seconds"

Everything is working fine. But now what i want is for the child process to run in the background. Meaning i do not want to see its output. but i want it to run and exit.

Comment: Make the forked child fork again and in this grand child do the exec.

More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932592/why-fork-twice

Comment: I made the child fork a grandchild to exec. Then i made the child to return without waiting for the grandchi;d. I still see the grandchild's output =/

Comment: Will you invoke your program from a login shell or at boot time as a system process?  A "daemon" (your tag) is one thing, "backgrounding" (your wording) is one of two things, and suppressing or redirecting output (perhaps your need?) is yet another thing. What, precisely, do you want?

Answer (score 0):

To make the child process run in the background, you need to make it a [daemon process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29).

There are few steps to follow to make it a daemon process..

1. Fork off the parent process
2. Change file mode mask (umask)
3. Open any logs for writing
4. Create a unique Session ID (SID)
5. Change the current working directory to a safe place
6. Close standard file descriptors

For a better explanation, see [this](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html).