# Spawning a non-child process in python

Tags: python, process, subprocess, popen

I need to create spawn off a process in python that allows the calling process to exit while the child is still running.  What is an effective way to do this?

Note:  I'm running on a UNIX environment.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon

Answer (score 4):

Terminating the parent process does not terminate child processes in Unix-like operating systems, so you don't need to do anything special.  Just start your subprocesses with `subprocess.Popen` and terminate the main process.  The orphaned processes will automatically be adopted by init.

Comment: I would think so, but for whatever reason the parent won't exit until that other subprocess completes.

There's a php file calling the function, which basically needs to launch off this subprocess and the return some information quickly.

Comment: Sven is right; I just validated it with a quick script consisting of `p = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sleep', '60'])`. Something else must be at work.

Comment: @themcementality: Are you by any chance using `subprocess.call()`?  This will wait for the child to finish.