# Opening Application in Python

Tags: python

I want to open an application with Python, that doesnt close even if the python program stops running...
If we take Spotify as an example:

```
import os

x = "C:\\Users\\49174\\AppData\Roaming\\Spotify\\Spotify.exe"
os.popen(x)
```

Comment: I'm afraid you've forgotten to ask a question, you've made a statement. What is the *exact* issue you're facing?

Comment: Use: `os.system(x)`

Comment: Like with popen, the App closes after I stop running my program... But I want it to stay open after closing the program

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316369/spawning-a-non-child-process-in-python suggests try `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code you have posted.  I've written and tested a similar example to open the calculator, and it remains open after the script closed. I've tested using both a function using `__main__`, and a script as you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to pass an additional parameter (`creationflags`) to `Popen`. Something like this should work (however, I do not have a Windows machine to check):

```py
import subprocess

creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | subprocess.subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS | subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW

x = "C:\\Users\\49174\\AppData\Roaming\\Spotify\\Spotify.exe"
subprocess.Popen(x, creationflags=creationflags)
```

Comment: This works on Windoze. Strangely enough ... so does the OP's original code.

Comment: I tried it, but as soon as I closed the program, spotify closed as well...

Comment: I still think that the issue is with the `creationflags`. I've added some more flags that could be useful - see updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os
os.startfile("C:\\Users\\49174\\AppData\Roaming\\Spotify\\Spotify.exe")
```