# Trying to kill a spawned process ends ups with a defunct process

Tags: c, linux, process, zombie-process

**Scenario:**
I'm developing a daemon monitoring application which starts and stops daemons on  by request (TCP-IP).
To achieve that, after forking, I'm calling `setsid()` in order to "detach" the new process from the parent (the monitoring process).

When I try to kill one of the processes the monitoring application created it ends up defuncted.

Here's my code:

```
int retval;
char* arg_list[] = {
  NULL      /* The argument list must end with a NULL.  */
};
retval = fork();
if (retval == 0)
{
    umask(0);
    setsid();
    execv(LBSDPATH, arg_list);
    exit(0);
}
```

As I understand, defunct/zombie process means that the parent haven't joined with the process yet. don't `setsid()` solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent needs to call `wait()` or `waitpid()` to have the child process be "freed" out of the defunct/zombie state.

This could be done in a parent's thread, as well as in a parent's signal handler servering the `SIGCHLD` signal received upon a child's death.

---

**Update**

Refering the need to have a child reparented to `init` to let it live as a damon as stated in a comment by *Mellowcandle*:

Just `fork()` twice. That is: the first `fork()`ed process just `fork()`s off another one.

Let the secondly `fork()`ed process do the `exec*()`, and let the first `fork()ed` process end.

When then first `fork()`ed process ends, its child (the secondly `fork()`ed process and with it it successor: the `exec*()`'ed one) is inherited by `init` which then handles the `SIGCHLD`/the death of this child.

Comment: I know that, but I want the process that I spawn to work independently, like a daemon.

Comment: @Mellowcandle: Then `fork()` twice. Let the secondly `fork()`ed process do the `exec*()`, and the first `fork()`ed process end. When then first `fork()`ed process dies, its children (the secondly `fork()`ed process and with it the `exec*()`'ed one) are inherited by `init` which then handles the `SIGCHLD`/the death of the child.

Comment: I don't think that I explained myself right, please see my edit to the qustion.

Comment: I recommend that you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388 , and when you've read the whole thing, and think you understand it, read it a second time just to make sure. I'm pretty sure you'll find your answer in there.

Comment: @mellowcandle: Please see *Elchonon Edelson*'s comment above.

Comment: @alk Thanks, it solved my problem, if you write this as the answer I will accept the answer !