# how to deploy a lisp image with swank, and run as a daemon

Tags: deployment, lisp, daemon, swank

As seid in the title, I want to deploy a Lisp image which is runnable
with Swank.  This can be done by using the image dump function
provided by lisp implementations.  But how can it run as a daemon?

`Detachtty` does a good job, but when I deploy, detachtty is required
by the user; I don't like this solution, I just want a standalone one.

Restas-daemon and sb-daemon may be another choice, but both are
SBCL-related.  Is there a portable solution, or one just for Clozure
CL?

I tried the `daemon` library from quicklisp too, but when I started
Swank in it, it hung.  I could see in the proc file system that the
socket file descriptors were destroyed.

Now I have no idea.

Does anyone have something to advise?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to daemonize it you can use sb-posix:fork under SBCL to perform double fork (see [What is the reason for performing a double fork when creating a daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon)). I believe other implementations have POSIX API as well.

If you just want the lisp process to run while the system is running even after you logout then use GNU screen. It let you detach without terminating your (lisp) process.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [cl-daemonize](https://github.com/mishoo/cl-daemonize). From the description, "A tool to daemonize a Lisp process without the need for screen/detachtty".