# process that don't have file descriptor

Tags: linux, unix, file-descriptor

when I do

```
ls proc/[pid]/fd
```

sometimes I don't get output, It seems that there are no file descriptor in that file.

What does that mean when a process doesn't have file descriptor?

Comment: `/proc/[pid]/fd` is a **directory**, not a file.

Comment: It means a process has no files open. I imagine (didn't check the source code) that `cron` would close its fds before going into waiting mode.

Comment: @larsmans then why/when a process don't need stdin, stdout, and stderr? thanks for your answer

Comment: If it doesn't need to communicate? `cron` just waits until a specified time to execute jobs. The only way to communicate with it is via signals, which don't need file descriptors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process in question is more likely a [deamon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) — daemon processed will [intentionally close standard file descriptors](http://www.itp.uzh.ch/~dpotter/howto/daemonize) in order to [avoid hanging onto their resources.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon) (They will also `chdir` to the root directory, invoke an extra `fork()` and perform a number of more obscure operations for the same reason.)

Comment: Many daemons will still have some FDs, open, though, to local sockets, logs, etc.

Comment: @larsmans Agreed - in fact, most of them do. But, given a program with no open files, I'd first assume it to be a daemon of some sort.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Sorry I can't +1 because I'm new here.