# C daemon - Release and delete a lockfile

Tags: c, locking, daemon

While daemonizing my program in C using code "stolen" from [this webpage](http://www.enderunix.org/docs/eng/daemon.php) upon initialisation the daemon creates a lockfile which stores the process pid thusly:

```
:
lfp=open(LOCK_FILE,O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0640);
if (lfp<0) exit(1);                  /* can not open */
if (lockf(lfp,F_TLOCK,0)<0) exit(0); /* can not lock */
sprintf(str,"%d\n",getpid());
write(lfp,str,strlen(str));          /* store pid in file */
:
```

The webpage doesn't seem to bother with cleaning up after the daemon terminates. In fact, searching the web I cannot find a way to handle this.
All examples of daemonizing C-code will create a lockfile, but none remove it afterwards. 
How should I unlock and then remove the pidfile assuming that I can catch SIGTERM and exit gracefully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock itself is automatically released:

> [reference](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html):
>   File locks are released as soon as the process holding the locks closes some
>   file descriptor for the file.

To remove the file you can use [unlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html). I suspect that the lock file is kept around since future invocations of the program will re-recreate it, thus reducing overhead.

Comment: I would think keeping stale lock files containing an expired pid might not be desirable.

Comment: @Mausy5043 You're right, but I don't see any pid in there: it is just an empty file.

Comment: You're right. I added the next two lines from the code to the OP to improve the context.

Comment: Yes, in that case it is much better to delete the file on exit. It will require some code changes as you can't simply `exit` anymore.

Comment: FYI, there is an [atexit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) function that allows you to register shutdown code.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've got it now. Here's what I have: https://github.com/Mausy5043/myCtest/tree/master/daemon2  .

Comment: There seems to be no consensus either way. I choose to `fork` twice. Sources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485204/why-fork-twice-while-daemonizing    &    http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/

Comment: Ah, interesting, didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

You can unlock explicitly using `F_ULOCK`. By the way from `fcntl` manpage (which is used on linux by `lockf`) it is indicated that locks are removed on file close or process end.

So after dying the daemon do not hold any lock. It can so open the file and set a new lock.