# What's the objection to double-forking daemons and session leaders?

Tags: unix, daemon

(Related to: approx. 1000 questions related to daemonizing a process.)

I've been doing double-fork forever on the base *"because Stevens says so"*.

This works, of course, and 99.9% of the time it makes no noticeable difference, but it is slightly less efficient than I'd like for a daemon process that should start (and shutdown/restart) as fast as possible with as little downtime in between as can be achieved.
No, `fork` still is not precisely a lightweight syscall, so if there is no absolutely urgent reason of doing it twice, I'd be most happy to skip it once.

I understand the purpose of a single fork with the intermediate parent exiting (technically, that's already *two* forks, one being done by the shell), this orphans the daemon process, makes init adopt it, and allows a presumed shell to return to the prompt (or continue executing a batch file, whatever).

`setsid()` will now place the daemon process in a new session, so by definition it will be in a session different from the one used by the terminal. You care about that because closing the shell/terminal would kill the daemon otherwise, which is arguably undesirable.
The daemon process is now *also* the session leader (and process leader, and sole process) of that new session.

Now... you are to fork a second (actually, third) time to guarantee that the daemon is *not* the session leader because this is apparently a bad thing. It's a bit difficult to find a good explanation as to why it is a bad thing, but presumably it allows opening a terminal by accident and making it the controlling terminal of the daemon. Which, I guess, would again mean having it killed when that terminal is closed.

Here we are at the part that I don't understand. Out of the blue, I wouldn't even know how to open a controlling terminal (open `/dev/tty`?), nor why I'd want to do this, nor how it could happen accidentially, even more so as `chroot` will make it somewhat difficult to open haphazard files in `/dev` even deliberately, assuming that e.g. a daemon naively opens files based on non-validated user requests and you're trying to be purposely malicious.

Thus, what exactly am I trying to defend against with this second fork? Is being a session leader actually a practical, not-entirely-theoretical issue at all?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon