# Fork a Python subprocess to survive interpreter, SSH death, nuclear war

Tags: python, django, subprocess

This has been a two day struggle, and I am quite stuck.

**TLDR**: From within a Python shell (`>>> "like this"`), start a Python script that survives `quit()` and `me@terminal:~$ exit`.

---

**I have tried:**

- various daemonizing functions that implement `os.fork()`
- creating/calling a shell script with `Popen` and `&` appended
- `subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "command.py"])` in several forms

**Toy Code** - Python 3.6

```
class MyClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        super().__init__()
        self.filepath = filepath

    def run(self):
        import time
        i = 0
        while True:  # Count to 50 in a file forever
            if i > 50: i = 0
            with open(self.filepath, "a") as afile:
                afile.writelines("This is msg {}\n".format(i))
            i += 1
            time.sleep(1)
```

How can I run this `Thread` from within the Python shell in such a way that it doesn't die when I close my interpreter and close my SSH terminal?

---

**Real Code** Django-managed DB consumption of PubNub messages

See `# TODO` line, near center. The `PNRunner` class instances will be started and killed dynamically within the construct of a Django app, so I can't just start them at boot with a shell script.

[image: what I actually want to do]

Comment: `nohup python command.py &`?

Comment: @SeanPianka Unfortunately that didn't seem to work empirically. I'm not sure WHY, but c'est la vie. It's actually the first thing I looked at.

Comment: I believe this can be done with a double fork (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon). There is a python example here (https://gist.github.com/Ma233/dd1f2f93db5378a29a3d1848288f520e).

Comment: @OllinBoerBohan I think you are correct. I have tried a couple times and it seems I'm not skilled enough to make it actually work... I see the example there, so I will muddle through that for a time.

Comment: Per discussion in the linked thread, you can try just using https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/ and see if that works

Comment: @OllinBoerBohan I clearly lack system knowledge here. The (nearly exact) implementation of `Daemon` I am working on calls `os.fork()`, but returns a non-zero PID and `sys.exit`s every time. Which kills the interpreter, and nothing is left running. So I am quite flummoxed.

Comment: This is now functional! Thank you. The breakthrough was in two simple realizations: First - `change MyClass to subclass Daemon, not Thread`. Second - `getting exit code 0 means it's working`. So I am grateful. Thank you. I will accept an answer posted here reflecting this if you want to post it.