# Is the process created with python `mutliprocessing.Process().daemon=True`, a real daemon process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have written a server which accepts a requests on certain port and forks a new daemon to handle each of those requests. I am doing forking with [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html). The basic code (with no port listening logic, as its not my doubt here) looks like this:

**Code (mu_min.py)**

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mup
import sys
import os

def worker(name):
    a = 0

    while(a < 5):
        print(name,":",a)
        a = a+1
        time.sleep(2)
        pass 

    print("Exiting worker: ", name, "(", os.getpid(), ")")

def start_server():
    b = 0

    while(b<3):
        new_worker = mup.Process(target=worker,args=('worker-'+str(b),))
        new_worker.daemon = True
        new_worker.start()
        b = b + 1
        time.sleep(3)

    time.sleep(3600)

start_server()
```

**The output**

```
worker-0 : 0
worker-0 : 1
worker-0 : 2
worker-0 : 3
worker-0 : 4
Exiting worker:  worker-0 ( 32831 )
worker-1 : 0
worker-1 : 1
worker-1 : 2
worker-1 : 3
worker-1 : 4
Exiting worker:  worker-1 ( 32834 )
worker-2 : 0
worker-2 : 1
worker-2 : 2
worker-2 : 3
worker-2 : 4
Exiting worker:  worker-2 ( 32837 )
```

**`ps` command output**

If I continuously run `ps` command in other terminal, I get following output:

```
[user@machine mu_min]$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
[user@machine mu_min]$ python3 mu_min.py > mu_min_nix_out &
[1] 32830
[user@machine mu_min]$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 32830  25898  32830  25898  |           \_ python3
 32831  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3
[user@machine mu_min]$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 32830  25898  32830  25898  |           \_ python3
 32831  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3
 32834  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3
[user@machine mu_min]$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 32830  25898  32830  25898  |           \_ python3
 32831  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3
 32834  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3
 32837  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3
[user@machine mu_min]$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 32830  25898  32830  25898  |           \_ python3
 32831  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
 32834  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3
 32837  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3
[user@machine mu_min]$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 32830  25898  32830  25898  |           \_ python3
 32831  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
 32834  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
 32837  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3
[user@machine mu_min]$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 32830  25898  32830  25898  |           \_ python3
 32831  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
 32834  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
 32837  32830  32830  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
```

I have following doubts

1. [multiprocessing doc page](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon) says following:

   > Additionally, these are not Unix daemons or services, they are normal processes that will be terminated (and not joined) if non-daemonic processes have exited.

   So isn't multiprocessing creating real daemons (as explained in below doubt)? Also I dont get meaning of "that will be terminated (and not joined) if non-daemonic processes have exited." What does it mean?
2. I prepared similar code with double forking using `os.fork()` handling `signal.SIGCHLD`. Handling `signal.SIGCHLD` seems to not leave back defunct processes. Also, it seems that, due to double forking, any processes 
   created were created with `PPID=1`, making them proper daemons. Notice that in above `ps` command output `PPID` of defunct processes is not 1. So they seem not to be proper daemons. Is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your first question:

These processes aren't real Unix daemons, they're "daemon" in the same sense as daemon threads within a process.

If your main process finishes and a secondary non-daemon process is still running, the main process will "join" it, i.e. wait for it to finish before exiting. If the secondary process is a daemon, however, it will be terminated when the main process finishes.

Comment: Does this answers my doubts? Which I have very specifically put in points.

Comment: This answers your first question.

Comment: So those daemons are just child threads for which parent process don't wait for completion...? Is this the definition of "daemon"?

Comment: They're actual processes, not threads, but they behave like this.

Comment: But is it desired behavior for so called daemons? Does it follow [standard daemon creation idioms](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#correct-daemon-behaviour) and [double forking for daemon creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/)?