# Is forking in a daemon still necessary when using systemd?

Tags: fork, daemon, systemd

I created a script which is supposed to run as a daemon, controlled by systemd. I came across ancient questions like [What is the reason for performing a double fork when creating a daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon) and ancient documentation, which suggests that daemons should fork to detach from a terminal.

But in 2020, using systemd, all of this seems obsolete to me. As far as I understand (with support from https://jdebp.eu/FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html), there is no need to detach from any terminal, no need to avoid zombie processes etc. The whole forking-and-exiting only makes sense to me if I want to start the daemon manually from a terminal and not with systemd.

Am I right or is there still any benefit from forking inside a daemon and exiting the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The forking is now 100% handled by the systemd environment so there is really no need to do anything in that arena. It even saves the PID which you can access in the `StopExec=...` as `$MAINPID`:

```
StopExec=/bin/kill "$MAINPID"
```

If your daemon has a forking capability, you can use it with the forking type:

```
[Service]
type=forking
```

But if you don't have any forking mechanism in your daemon, don't implement it. It's useless.

Note that from the command line, you can always use the `&` to start it in the background. That's explicit. People can clearly understand how that works.

Another point, many people would use a PID file to save that identifier and use it to kill the process on a `stop`. That PID file was also useful to prevent the administrator from starting a second instance of the same service. Again, systemd takes care of that. You can have at most one instance of any service.