# How can I kill this process?

Tags: process, system-administration

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND     
3316 root      20   0  5356 1176  736 R 32.7  2.0   1650:09 lighttpd
```

It's runnning on my dd-wrt router. I tried `kill -9 3316`, but I can still see the process in `top`

`service lighttpd stop` doesn't work.

The lighttpd process doesn't work (I mean one can't visit my router via http), but it consumes the 80 port.

```
root@DD-WRT:~# netstat -tulpn
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3316/lighttpd
```

Could anyone tell me what is probably wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Try this link, I think it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694720/how-is-it-possible-that-kill-9-for-a-process-on-linux-has-no-effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `/etc/init.d/lightttpd stop`

Comment: The lighttpd process still lives.

Comment: You'll probably have to reboot, if you're trying to stop lighttpd from running at all I suggest you edit your init scripts so that it doesn't run on start up.