# Task "dying" state during uninterruptible syscall with SIGKILL

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, signals, system-calls

I read [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485644/what-does-a-program-do-when-its-sent-sigkill-signal) about `SIGKILL` and was confused about the following statements:

> only some system calls are interruptible, so the kernel internally
>   marks the process as being in a special "dying" state until the system
>   calls or I/O operations are resolved

...

> Once any in-process kernel routines are resolved, the process state is
>   changed from "dying" to "dead" and the kernel begins cleaning it up

But I can't find any confirmation on this in kernel sources. The task states are defined in [linux/sched.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/include/linux/sched.h#L60):

```
#define TASK_RUNNING            0x0000
#define TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE      0x0001
#define TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE    0x0002
#define __TASK_STOPPED          0x0004
#define __TASK_TRACED           0x0008
/* Used in tsk->exit_state: */
#define EXIT_DEAD               0x0010
#define EXIT_ZOMBIE             0x0020
#define EXIT_TRACE              (EXIT_ZOMBIE | EXIT_DEAD)
/* Used in tsk->state again: */
#define TASK_PARKED             0x0040
#define TASK_DEAD               0x0080
#define TASK_WAKEKILL           0x0100
#define TASK_WAKING             0x0200
#define TASK_NOLOAD             0x0400
#define TASK_NEW                0x0800
#define TASK_STATE_MAX          0x1000
```

And there are no any "dying" state neither in linux/sched.h nor in other scheduler files. Can someone clarify which exactly task state is used to mark task as "dying" while non-interruptible syscall?

Answer (score 0):

From the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694720/how-is-it-possible-that-kill-9-for-a-process-on-linux-has-no-effect) it would seem that "dying" state would correspond to the "uninterruptible sleep" state:

> As noted in comments to the OP, a process status (`STAT`) of `D` indicates that the process is in an "uninterruptible sleep" state. In real-world terms, this generally means that it's waiting on I/O and can't/won't do anything - including dying - until that I/O operation completes.

Out of the states in `linux/sched.h` it would seem that `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` is the one corresponding to the uninterruptible sleep state. From the ["Understanding Linux Process States"](https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/processstates_20120831.pdf) (Yogesh Babar):

> An Uninterruptible sleep state is one that won't handle a signal right away. It will wake only as a result of awaited-upon resource becoming available or after a time-out occurs during that wait (if the time-out is specified when the process is put to sleep). The Uninterruptible state is mostly used by device drivers waiting for disk or network I/O. When the process is sleeping uninterruptibly, signals accumulated during the sleep are noticed when the process returns from the system call or trap. In Linux systems. the command **ps -l** uses the letter D in the state field (S) to indicate that the process is in an Uninterruptible sleep state. In that case, the process state flag is set as follows:
>
> `p->state = TASK_UNINTERRUPTABLE`